# fatal error after a isset?

Tags: php, isset

```
 exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Illegal string offset 'tax''
```

This is the fatal error I get

```
        Log::error(print_r($pax_group , true));
        Log::error(var_dump($pax_group));
        if(isset($pax_group["otherdetail"]["tax"]["details"]["detail"][0]))
                            {
                               // I get the fatal error at the foreach line
                                foreach($pax_group["otherdetail"]["tax"]["details"]["detail"] as $one_tax)
                                {
                                    $detail = new Otherdetail;
                                    $detail->occ_paxs_id = $px->id;
                                    $detail->code = $one_tax["code"];
                                    $detail->amount = $one_tax["amt"];
                                    $detail->B2Bamount = $one_tax["amt"];
                                    $detail->save();
                                }
                            }
```

this is the value I have inside otherdetail : `<otherdetail>0</otherdetail>`

Anyone know how is it possible that I go through the isset when I have no ["tax"]["details"]["detail"][0] inside `<otherdetail>0</otherdetail>` ?

EDIT: I am now able to reproduce it. this is what I get inside my print_r and var_dump log

```
[2017-09-27 14:57:28] production.ERROR: Array
(
    [cost] => 1033.60
    [retail] => 1157.632
    [wholesale] => 1157.632
    [othertotal] => 0.00
    [otherdetail] => 0
)
 [] []
[2017-09-27 14:57:28] production.ERROR:  [] []
[2017-09-27 14:57:28] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Illegal string offset 'tax'' in /home/*****************:1525
```

More xml :

```
<prices>
<total>
<cost>943.85</cost>
<wholesale>1021.6</wholesale>
<retail>1021.6</retail>
<othertotal>223.58</othertotal>
</total>
<paxgroup num="1">
<qty>2</qty>
<fromage>20</fromage>
<toage>120</toage>
<cost>471.93</cost>
<wholesale>510.80</wholesale>
<retail>510.80</retail>
<othertotal>111.79</othertotal>
<fare_type>PB</fare_type>
<components>
<AIR>
<cost>148.00</cost>
<retail>148</retail>
<wholesale>148</wholesale>
<othertotal>111.79</othertotal>
</AIR>
<HOT>
<cost>323.93</cost>
<retail>362.8016</retail>
<wholesale>362.8016</wholesale>
<othertotal>0.00</othertotal>
<otherdetail>0</otherdetail>
</HOT>
</components>
</paxgroup>
</prices>
```

json:

```
{"prices":{"total":{"cost":943.85,"wholesale":1021.6,"retail":1021.6,"othertotal":223.58},"paxgroup":[{"qty":"2","fromage":"20","toage":"120","cost":"471.93","wholesale":"510.80","retail":"510.80","othertotal":"111.79","fare_type":"PB","components":{"AIR":{"cost":"148.00","retail":148,"wholesale":148,"othertotal":"111.79"},"HOT":{"cost":"323.93","retail":362.8016,"wholesale":362.8016,"othertotal":"0.00","otherdetail":"0"}}}]}}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Is there other code you haven't included?

Comment: Do a var_dump on pax_group and post the code:
echo(var_dump($pax_group));

Comment: Me Too I can't reproduce it, but I am logging the raw xml before saving in db  and this is what I had in otherdetail <otherdetail>0</otherdetail>

Comment: @TimHinz I edited my post. I have nothing with var_dump but I see my array with print_r

Comment: var_dump should be outputting data, if it's not that means your variable has other major issues going on with is. Can you provide the complete XML file so I can take a look at it and further see what's going on.

Comment: Also How are you loading your XML?

Comment: @TimHinz I receive json but the whole booking is saved in xml, I added a sample of the xml/json of this booking. I can't give you all the xml/json

Comment: It would appear the data you're trying to access `$pax_group["otherdetail"]["tax"]["details"]["detail"][0]` is not in your JSON data. `otherdetail` is a single value - not a collection of data with child elements.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if(isset($pax_group['otherdetail']) && isset($pax_group['otherdetail']['tax']) && isset($pax_group['otherdetail']['tax']['details']) && isset($pax_group['otherdetail']['tax']['details']['detail'])){
  //...
}
```

Comment: That's redundant code that provides no purpose and is inefficient.